# How to get max value of a column from two tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have one table named 'posts' and one table named 'threads'. Both have the column called 'total_id' which is an integer. 
Now, how to get from those two tables the 1 highest value (max) in the 'total_id' column? (MySQL)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get it as follows:

```
SELECT Greatest(
          (SELECT Max(total_id) FROM posts),
          (SELECT Max(total_id) FROM threads)
       )
```

Comment: Cool it works. @trincot is it possible to use with it the LIMIT to get the second highest value from both of them?

Comment: No, `greatest` takes the highest and there is no `limit` clause that works with it. To get the second highest would be a different question. Feel free to post one. I will have a look at it ;-)

Comment: @Naveh `SELECT total_id FROM posts ORDER BY total_id DESC LIMIT 1,1` will get the second highest.

Comment: @Barmar, the question is regarding using two tables at the same time, your query only gives one.

Comment: @trincot you realise that you can post 1 question every hour and 30 mins right? :\

Comment: @Naveh Use `UNION` to combine the two tables.

Comment: @trincot, thank you for your helpful assistance, it worked perfectly as I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Though it's not really very clear what's your expected result but in case you want max of `total_id` including both tables data? If yes, then you can do a `UNION` and then get the highest value like

```
select max(total_id) as max_total_id from (
select total_id from posts
union
select total_id from threads ) xxx;
```